# update mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to update my users table using php.

```
$update_query="
UPDATE `users` SET `name`='$addname',
`lastname`='$addlastname',
`password`='$addpsswrd',
`email`='$addemail'
where `username`='$modifyusername'
";
echo $update_query; 
 if( mysql_query($update_query) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$req.'<br>'.mysql_error()))
echo  "Lignes modifiées : ", mysql_affected_rows();
```

But I always get :

```
UPDATE `users` SET `name`='Jolia ',`lastname`='roberta', `password`='password1234',`email`='roberta.joli@hotmail.fr' where `username`='user11'
```

**Lignes modifiées : 0**

How can I fix this? the user11 exist in my database and I tried to copy past this query as it is in the output echo message I get 0 modified line so  how can I fixed on the php part?

Answer (score 0):

> When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the query.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: I have changed all the values with the update query! but it doesn't work still have 0 modified rows

Comment: **>_modified line so I just make the ' on the same line:_**
i don't see your modify, two strings are identical

Comment: the first query was the query I hve used on php file and it doesn't work, the second is the same query used on the phpadmin part and it work if i changed the last quote to make it in the same line it's just to check the query! exactly it's the same string I haven't change it

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure , but my suggestion is try to remove the single quotation marks  ['] from the column name. ps: this is my first time answer question on stackoverflow

like

```
$update_query="
UPDATE users SET name='$addname',
lastname='$addlastname',
password='$addpsswrd',
email='$addemail'
where username='$modifyusername'
";
echo $update_query; 
 if( mysql_query($update_query) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$req.'<br>'.mysql_error()))
echo  "Lignes modifiées : ", mysql_affected_rows();
```